# I believe my skills are better than what I have produced so far - should I avoid making a portfolio or just show off what I have so far?

Tags: portfolio

I am a Master's student and started my freelance design company six months ago. What I have designed in the past years is fine, but I believe my skills now are a degree better. I just haven't had the chance to use them yet.

I am unsure if I should showcase what I got or don't do it to avoid getting as an amateur.

Answer (score 7):

Speaking from experience, I'd always say it's better to show a few key projects than nothing at all.

From a clients point of view they need at least a little bit of proof that you can design. Why would they risk hiring somebody who seems to have no track record of working on any projects?

Your number one goal at the minute seems to be getting some more projects. Sure, if your portfolio isn't high quality you're probably not going to attract high quality clients, but if you view every project you get as THE project - you can turn a low budget, crappy brief into a fantastic case study that'll set the bar for future projects!

Answer (score 2):

After almost every project, I have learned so much that if I were to do that same project again, I could do it better. In that sense, by the time any piece is done, I am already better than it, so the problem you are describing is just the name of the game. Show what you have.